# Posting Forms and accessing Databse from Android Application

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, forms

I am a new Android Developer and I am making a project for the same.
My project is to create an application that will take the username and password as inputs for the log in from a registered user and proceed if the credentials are correct.
Now, I want to do this thing by posting forms like it is done on the web browsers. Also, please make sure that I don't want to create any new user from the application. Only the registered users can use this application. How shall i make these forms and post them so that i can retrieve the information from database.
PS. The details of all the users are stored in a database in MySQL. So, I need my application to post forms and check the details from this database.

Comment: Do you have any question?

Comment: @eddie Yes, I said that i want to know how to create these forms and post them to the database from where i want to retrieve the information like username, password, etc.

Comment: You can use a http client like: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ There are MANY out there. This is true for a native app, you can also embed a html form in a WebView.